# Outlook not rendering background-image css property

Tags: html, css, image, outlook, background-image

When a user creates an account on my application they receive an email with the credentials.

This email contains two images, one with the logo and the other as a background image.

The logo one does render in outlook and there are no problems with it, it is programmed as follows:

```
<img align="center" alt="" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/......">
```

The background image is the opposite, it does not render in outlook and it is programmed as follows:

```
background-image:url("https://gallery.mailchimp.com/......");
```

Is there a solution for replacing the css property `background-image` by the `<img>` html tag and still keep the image in the background?

**UPDATE 1**

The HTML where the background image is:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" id="templateHeader" data-template-container>
```

The css for the`id = "templateHeader"`:

```
#templateHeader{
            background-color:#F7F7F7;
            background-image:url("https://gallery.mailchimp.com/......");
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-position:center;
            background-size:cover;
            border-top:0;
            border-bottom:0;
            padding-top:45px;
            padding-bottom:45px;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us the HTML that should display the background image, and the selector used to apply the background image?

Comment: @eskwayrd updated the question

Comment: It looks like your HTML+CSS is correct. However, it looks like some versions of OutLook don't support `background` styles, according to: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/background-image/

Comment: @eskwayrd That I already know, what I am asking for a ´background´ replacement

Comment: One strategy that might work is to place two images in your table cell, and apply positioning and z-index to achieve the effort you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A possible resolution for your problem is: wrap your `<table>` in a `<div>` and then in `<td align="center" valign="top" id="templateHeader" data-template-container>`, instead of the `background-image` image is on a separate CSS file, do it directly, using `background:url()`:

```
<td style="background:url("https://gallery.mailchimp.com/......"); top center /cover repeat;" align="center" valign="top" id="templateHeader" data-template-container>
```

If you want test it with a CSS file too: (**tested and working**)

```
#templateHeader{
            background: url("https://gallery.mailchimp.com/......");
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-position:center;
            background-size:cover;
            border-top:0;
            border-bottom:0;
            padding-top:45px;
            padding-bottom:45px;
        }
```

Comment: Tried that approach before, it does not work, Outlook 2016 desktop does not support any background property.

Comment: I was talking about the most recent... Outlook express... Why would you want it to work on previous outlook?

Comment: The world of business. Not every client has the most recent version of outlook, some of them are stuck on outlook 2003 (thankfully it works in that version). I can´t program thinking that everyone is up to date in software. This isn´t a normal commercial application for everyone, it´s a business-specific tool. @mindmaster

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
       body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }        
        #templateHeader{
            background-color:#F7F7F7;
            background-image:url("https://d1cr57qij2cwzh.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/EOA_OutlookImageSupport_Blog-1200x675.jpg");
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-position:center;
            background-size:cover;
            border-top:0;
            border-bottom:0;
            padding-top:250px;
            padding-bottom:250px;
        }
```

```html
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" id="templateHeader" data-template-container></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```